# Locked-out Samsung GALAXY Tab 3 asking for GMail pass and username

Tags: locked-out

My 8 year old son has locked himself out of his Samsung GALAXY Tab 3. It is now asking for GMail password and username. I have no clue what they are.

So far, I have tried:

- Hard reset, but it didn't work.
- Downloaded Samsung Kies and tried to update the tablet, but I need the password to proceed.

One more thing, we have new WiFi, so the tablet does not have the access code since I can't get into the Settings to change it.

Comment: I'm not a Samsung user, so I'm not sure, but I think it should be the GMail account used to setup your account for the first time, or maybe GMail account used for administrator (if it has multiple users). Who setup the tablet for the first time?

Comment: I think my husband did it with my son but we have tried all of gmail accounts he has and no luck!